# HTML5 Event Listing Semantics

Tags: html, events, seo, semantic-markup

Would it be correct to list each event as an `<article>` on an event listing page (given that each event is a listing from the detail page of said event. Should it be considered the same thing as blog (semantically). Also should there be any consideration of the event date/time when it comes to markup. Any referenced reading are welcome, I couldn't find any particulars!

```
<main>
 <article>Event 1 on date given</article>
 <article>Event 2 on date given</article>
 <article>Event 3 on date given</article>
</main>
```

or should each event be contained in a single article and wrapped with a typical div structure.

```
<article>
 <div> Event 1 on date given</div>
 <div> Event 2 on date given</div>
 <div> Event 3 on date given</div>
</article>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It’s appropriate to use the **`article` element** for events
   if using a sectioning content element is warranted.
2. A **sectioning content element** is warranted
   if it makes sense to list each event in the document outline.
3. It makes sense to list each event in the **document outline**
   if you provide enough content (where *enough*, of course, depends on the context).

So, for example,

if you just list the event name and the date, an `ul` element seems to be more appropriate:

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="/events/1">Event 1</a> (<time>2016-12-27</time>)</li>
  <li><a href="/events/2">Event 2</a> (<time>2016-12-27</time>)</li>
  <li><a href="/events/3">Event 3</a> (<time>2016-12-28</time>)</li>
</ul>
```

but if you provide more details, like a description, the organizer, etc., an `article` element for each event can make sense:

```html
<article>
  <header>
    <h2><a href="/events/1" rel="bookmark">Event 1</a></h2>
    <time>2016-12-27</time>
  </header>
  <p>…</p>
  <img src="" alt="" />
  <p>…</p>
  <footer><p>Organized by …</p></footer>
</article>

<article>
  <!-- event 2 -->
</article>

<article>
  <!-- event 3 -->
</article>
```

Comment: is this still the recommendation, i.e. state of the art?
How would you write a markup for a date range?
Would it be ok to write a markup like the following?
`<article><header><h3>...</h3><p>
<time datetime="2022-10-13">14th</time> to <time datetime="2022-10-18">October 18th, 2022</time></p></header>...</article>`