# Semantic HTML for list of events

Tags: html, semantic-markup

I have an Events page on my site that simply lists a bunch of upcoming events. The button would just link out to an external website. The design/content will look something like this: [image: event details]

How would I go about making this semantic?

Currently, I'm doing something like this:

```
<ul class="events__list">
  <li class="event">
    <h3 class="event__name">Event Title</h3>
    <time class="event__date">April 21-23, 2017</time>
    <p class="event__venue">Venue Location Name</p>
    <p class="event__address">123 Fourth St
      <br>City, STATE 01234
    </p>
    <a href="#" class="btn event__btn">Visit Website</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    ...
  </li>
  ...
</ul>
```

Would this be a case where using `<address>` makes sense if I were to replace the `<li>`s with `<article>`s. So something like this:

```
<div class="events__list">
  <article class="event">
    <h3 class="event__name">Event Title</h3>
    <time class="event__date">April 21-23, 2017</time>
    <address class="event__address">
      Venue Location Name<br>
      123 Fourth St<br>
      City, STATE 01234
    </address>
    <a href="#" class="btn event__btn">Visit Website</a>
  </article>
  <article>
    ...
  </article>
  ...
</div>
```

I'm trying to become more familiar with writing appropriate, semantic markup. How would you go about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whether or not `address` gets used, using the [`article`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-html51-20161101/sections.html#the-article-element) element for each event [is appropriate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41350675/1591669). While you could use a [`ul`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-html51-20161101/grouping-content.html#the-ul-element) in addition, it’s typically not needed.

If the address is the relevant contact for this event, using the [`address`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-html51-20161101/sections.html#the-address-element) element is appropriate. If it’s just the location of the event, but there is e.g. a different address for a contact person, the `address` element should be used for the latter.

If the external link goes to an event-specific page, you could use the [`bookmark`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-html51-20161101/links.html#link-type-bookmark) link type. But don’t use it if it’s just a link to e.g. the event location’s homepage.

Comment: This is very enlightening, thank you! Say for instance the external link goes to an event-specific page (like you mentioned) with additional contact information (say address, phone number, email, etc.), should I NOT use the `address` element on my site since it doesn't contain all relevant contact information?

Comment: @user2909019: I would still use `address` if you provide only a subset of the relevant contact information. If the external page has more/less of it shouldn’t affect your markup.

Comment: Also, would you put the external link inside of the `address` tag?

Comment: @user2909019: I guess both ways are possible (if the linked page contains the relevant contact information).